# How to import from a data file a numpy structured array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, structured-array

i'm trying to create an array which has 5 columns imported from a data file. The 4 of them are floats and the last one string.

The data file looks like this:

```
5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.9,3.0,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.7,3.2,1.3,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.6,3.1,1.5,0.2,Iris-setosa
5.0,3.6,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
5.4,3.9,1.7,0.4,Iris-setosa
4.6,3.4,1.4,0.3,Iris-setosa
5.0,3.4,1.5,0.2,Iris-setosa
```

I tried these:

```
data = np.genfromtxt(filename, dtype = "float,float,float,float,str", delimiter = ",")

data = np.loadtxt(filename, dtype = "float,float,float,float,str", delimiter = ",")
```

,but both codes import only the first column.

Why? How can i fix this?

Ty for your time! :)

Comment: Take a look at the `usecols` keyword in either of the functions you tried.

Comment: I tried! the same... 
The default that now i am using it supposed to take all the columns

Comment: @stevi, don't post input data as an image, post a testable text fragment

Comment: sorry, done!!!!

Comment: Your `dtype` should work, except for the size of the final string field.

Comment: Did you actually look at `data` and its `dtype`?  Or just see the `shape` (which will be 1d)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must specify correctly the `str` type : `"U20"` for exemple for 20 characters max :

```
data = np.loadtxt('data.txt', dtype = "float,"*4 + "U20", delimiter = ",")
```

seems to work :

```
array([( 5.1,  3.5,  1.4,  0.2, 'Iris-setosa'),
       ( 4.9,  3. ,  1.4,  0.2, 'Iris-setosa'),
       ( 4.7,  3.2,  1.3,  0.2, 'Iris-setosa'),
       ( 4.6,  3.1,  1.5,  0.2, 'Iris-setosa'),
       ( 5. ,  3.6,  1.4,  0.2, 'Iris-setosa'),
       ( 5.4,  3.9,  1.7,  0.4, 'Iris-setosa'),
       ( 4.6,  3.4,  1.4,  0.3, 'Iris-setosa'),
       ( 5. ,  3.4,  1.5,  0.2, 'Iris-setosa')],
      dtype=[('f0', '<f8'), ('f1', '<f8'), ('f2', '<f8'), ('f3', '<f8'), ('f4', '<U20')])
```

An other method using pandas give you an object array, but this slow down further computations :

```
In [336]: pd.read_csv('data.txt',header=None).values
Out[336]: 
array([[5.1, 3.5, 1.4, 0.2, 'Iris-setosa'],
       [4.9, 3.0, 1.4, 0.2, 'Iris-setosa'],
       [4.7, 3.2, 1.3, 0.2, 'Iris-setosa'],
       [4.6, 3.1, 1.5, 0.2, 'Iris-setosa'],
       [5.0, 3.6, 1.4, 0.2, 'Iris-setosa'],
       [5.4, 3.9, 1.7, 0.4, 'Iris-setosa'],
       [4.6, 3.4, 1.4, 0.3, 'Iris-setosa'],
       [5.0, 3.4, 1.5, 0.2, 'Iris-setosa']], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Seems correct but try table.shape, its shape is 8 while i want (8,5) :/
It looks like an array with one column that has tuples in each row.

Comment: It's normal with structured array. Pandas can help you for what you want. edited.

Comment: `dtype=None` should deduce the field dtypes correctly.

Comment: @hpaulj  I obtain with loadtxt : ValueError: could not convert string to float: b'Iris-setosa'

Comment: `genfromtxt` does the auto dtype better than `loadtxt`.